# `jlink` in java9 does not save resources in the exploded directory?

Tags: java, linker, resources, java-9, jlink

I am a little bit confused about `jlink`. I am able to compile my source files and then use `jlink` with the following command

```
jlink -p $JAVA_HOME/jmods:mymods:<a few jars separated by colon here> \
      --add-modules com.myModuleApp \
      --output outfolder \
      --launcher launch=com.myModuleApp/com.myModuleApp.Main
```

it returns a tree structure folder like this:

```
outfolder
├── bin
│   └── launch
├── conf
├── include
├── legal
├── lib
└── release
```

On `jlink --help` there is no mention of how to include `resources` using any  of its options.

I am able to run the launcher `launch` by double clicking it but then I get errors related to not  being able to find the resources *(naturally, as they are not in the outfolder)*.

However, even if I try to put the resources manually anywhere and everywhere in the directory tree, the `launch`er still is not able find the resources.

Is `jlink` designed to replace `javapackager` completely, partially, at all?

Can we deploy an app by `jlink`ing the modules in a Java 9 app and then just bundling it in a `jar`?

If we use `jlink`, how can we properly include the `resources` files in the `outfolder`?

~ thanks in advance ~

Comment: It would be useful if you could expand on what you mean by "resources"? For starters, I would expect the resources in your module to be in your module JAR (on the module path that you specify to jlink). Code in your module will be able to locate these via Class.getResourceXXX, exactly the same as when you run with the modular JAR on the module path.

Comment: hello, by `resources` I mean `.txt` files, Image icons for example, between others.

Comment: I understand [a module is, basically, the src files plus its data i.e.resources](https://medium.com/@chandra25ms/java9-modularity-part1-a102d85e9676). So, indeed I include resources within each module respectively as they are used. `jlink` does not produce a `jar` btw

Comment: If your module (be it packaged as a modular JAR or exploded on the file system) includes resources then jlink will include then in the run-time image. Is it possible that you've put the resources in a different directory tree so that they are not in the module specified to jlink?

Comment: the resource file, for example a `.txt` file, which is loaded by the module `com.myModuleApp` is at different directory levels as I am trying to solve this issue *(and understand better).* Running on `IntelliJ` works fine and I am not using `classpath`s. When I run `jlink` it does not save the resource into the exploded directory. **Note I use the command as shown in the question description**

Comment: Can you paste in the Class.getResourceXXX code that you use to locate the resource? If it works on the module path then it should work in the run-time image you create with jlink.

Comment: yes, `AboutDialog.class.getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")`

Comment: If hello.txt is in the same directory AboutDialog.class then it should work on either the module path or in the run-time image created by jlink. If you are saying that it's in a different directory tree and it works in IntelliJ then IntelliJ must be using `--patch-module` to augment the module with the resources in the other tree.

Comment: Actually, it is in the same directory as the `AboutDialog.class` so it finds it no problem there. The issue is that `jlink` does not copy it over in the exploded `outfolder`

Comment: jlink does copy resources. You can use `jimage list outfolder/lib/modules` to list all the resources in the generated run-time image and I would expect to see hello.txt listed under your module name.

Comment: `jimage` is very helpful. I can verify that `hello.txt` was not in the module. However, I looked into `mymods` which are just the `.class` compiled from `myModuleApp`  and `hello.txt` is not there either. So, I put the `helllo.txt` resource file to the same directory where `AboutDialog.class` is located. Now, I can corroborate that `jlink`, effectively, copies the resources , in this case `hello.txt`, in the module thanks @AlanBateman

Comment: Thanks for confirming. One thing that isn't clear is how this works in IntelliJ. Can you see if the IDE is sneaking in a --patch-module option to patch the module with the resources in the other directory tree? I can't otherwise explain how it could work in the IDE. Also can you confirm that you tested the module on the module path before trying jlink - I'll bet you would have found the issue there first.